# redirect to home page when i have dynamic url in next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

im geting redirect to home page when im trying to refresh this url  https://example/appointments/222/

i try to use Link and  but both give me the same thing

Comment: without code it's hard to say anything. post your _app.tsx and the code of the dynamic page.

Comment: i try to post app but its not allowed it's more characters  then the max here

Comment: Try to paste some code that might reproduce the problem, create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that helps others understand the problem, that will make it easier to help you.